# What is the best method to implement MVVM in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm

I'm trying to make a simple App to stretch my legs and implement MVVM using Flutter which I have never done.

On the main page of the App, I'm displaying items from a collection fetched from the backend. So my logic would be that when the page appears, the MainPageViewModel is initialized and the area that should display the collection should show a loader. During the initialization, the call to the back end is made. Once this call resolves, I would store the result in a variable and somehow notify the View that it can update its visuals, either to display an error or the collection that's been fetched. It's especially that notifying the view that it should update that stomps me. I'm also guessing it'd be good practice to not render the `view` until the `viewModel` has finished initializing.

I'm curious how you reckon this should be made. I know I could just dump it into a `FutureBuilder` but my goal here is to learn the MVVM concepts to start doing more complex stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Flutter is not a good match for MVVM, which is meant more for imperative frameworks.  In a reactive framework such as Flutter, the viewmodel is redundant, because we can craft the views to directly watch the models.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz so what kind of design pattern/architecture would you use? The only thing I can think of is doing the calls in a FutureBuilder and having the shared objects/DTOs separately in a models folder.

Comment: Straight MVC.  Views observe models.  Controllers process input events, update models, and inform views of model change.